# How to set timeout for onFailure event (Spring, Kafka)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to implement an asynchronous REST method of sending a message to Kafka in Spring MVC. Everything works, but when the server is unavailable, the onFailure event is processed for a long time. How to limit the response time in ListenableFuture for example to three seconds.

Here's my code:

```
@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

@Value("${spring.kafka.topic}")
String topic;

@RequestMapping("/test")
DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> test(
        @RequestParam(value = "message") String message
) {

    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, "testKey", message);

    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> sendResult) {
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("SUCCESS", HttpStatus.OK);
            deferredResult.setResult(responseEntity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("FAILURE", HttpStatus.OK);
            deferredResult.setResult(responseEntity);
        }

    });

    return deferredResult;
}
```

I tried to use a `REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG` property of Kafka and `.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method of ListenableFuture but havn't got desired result.

Comment: The `get()` should fail after the timeout; what is happening in that case?

Comment: @GaryRussell If I add `future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` before `return` I get following error in 60 seconds. Without this get-method I get correct "FAILURE" response in 60 seconds.


`HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.`

Comment: See my answer; you can reduce `max.block.ms`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because the producer blocks for 60 seconds (by default).

See [`max.block.ms` in the KafkaDocumentation for producer configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs).

> `max.block.ms` The configuration controls how long KafkaProducer.send() and KafkaProducer.partitionsFor() will block.These methods can be blocked either because the buffer is full or metadata unavailable.Blocking in the user-supplied serializers or partitioner will not be counted against this timeout.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I needed!