# Producer taking longer time to throw exception in case of kafka broker down

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to handle the case if Kafka Broker is down on the Kafka Producer end then its taking longer time to show the below error.

Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for logging-0: 30030 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

How to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

The producer waits for `request.timeout.ms` for a response from the broker.

> The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the client will
>   wait for the response of a request. If the response is not received
>   before the timeout elapses the client will resend the request if
>   necessary or fail the request if retries are exhausted. This should be
>   larger than replica.lag.time.max.ms (a broker configuration) to reduce
>   the possibility of message duplication due to unnecessary producer
>   retries.

It is set to 30000ms by default. Be careful if you try reducing it as if too short it can cause the producer to retry too quickly and produce duplicates.

Comment: I cant find replica.lag.time.max.ms in server.properties can you pls tell how to configure this in broker

Comment: See it in the broker configuration documentation: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: Also see `max.block.ms` [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487619/how-to-set-timeout-for-onfailure-event-spring-kafka/49494338#49494338) which can affect getting metadata when the app is first started and the broker is down.